# How to set Database Audit Specification for a domain group (SQL server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, audit

I'm trying to set Database Audit Specification for a domain group that has a sysadmin role on my sql server (2012).

I did the following steps:

1. I created a db user - "TechTeam".
2. I defined Server audit (destination : Application Log)
3. I defined a Login for the domain group "domain\myteam" (under User mapping --> User, I entered the db user I created on step 1 - TechTeam).
4. I created a Database Audit Specification (Audit Action Type: UPDATE, Object Class: database, Object Name: mydbname, Principal: TechTeam).

My problem:
If the Login "domain\myteam" has a server role "sysadmin", nothing shows up on the event viewer.
But, if I uncheck the "sysadmin" server role on the login dialog, the events are created.
On both cases I did the same action - updating a table row on mydbname. The action was made by a different user from domain\myteam.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server database audit action requires a principal be specified. When that principal is a group or user that has SYSADMIN the audit will NOT audit. I speculate sysadmin members are shuffled to the DBO group which takes precedence.

However, if you create another action and specify DBO as the principal name it will audit all action's by ALL sysadmins. This is not precisely what you may be looking to do, since it casts a wider net than just the group/user that has sysadmin membership that you want to audit.

My source: 
Auditing Administrators

"Members of the sysadmin fixed server role are identified as the dbo user in each database. To audit actions of the administrators, audit the actions of the dbo user."

[SQL Server Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine)